# Singular UITableViewDiffableDataSource used by multiple tableviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How would I go about implementing multiple UITableViewControllers all using the same UITableViewDiffableDataSource object.

The constructor takes only one tableview object like so

```
dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, UUID>(tableView: tableView) {
    (tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, itemIdentifier: UUID) -> UITableViewCell? in
    // configure and return cell
}
```

Which makes me think it is not even possible to make a UITableViewDiffableData reusable

Comment: It's probably possible, it just depends on how much you want to share. Is the code for configuring each cell different? You could pass the configure closure as a parameter.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez It is so that when a change is made on one tableview it is reflected on all the other tableviews that use this datasource object